# What does the AVPlayer Special Considerations mean?

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, avplayer

In the [AVPlayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s method `replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:` is a Special Considerations note which says:

> **Special Considerations**
>   The new item must have the same compositor as the item it replaces, or have no compositor.

I am not sure what they mean? What do they mean with compositor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `videoComposition` of the new `AVPlayerItem` must be the same than the item being replaced or shouldn't have composition at all.